# Pandas DataFrame loop through all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have very simple line of code:

```
df[df.RESP == 0].CCOL
```

where I list DataFrame (df) CCOL values if value in RESP column is equal to zero.

However, if I add an array (e.g. CNames=[CCOL1, CCOL2, CCOL3...]) and try to loop through the array in order to get every column values IF RESP == 0 the above line of code could not be implemented.

I tried this way:

```
for c in CNames:
    df[df.RESP == 0].c
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'attribute' acccess to the columns, but you can also get the columns using the name in `[ ]` ('getitem'), like `df['CCOL']`, and in this way you can use a variable as the column name.

In this case:

```
for c in CNames:
    df.loc[df.RESP == 0, c]
```

Using `loc` like above is recommended. You can also do `df[df.RESP == 0][c]`, but this chained indexing is not always guaranteed to work if you also want to assign values to that selection.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand where the problem was.